# Ethernet communication protocol: reestablishing lost communication

Tags: communication, ethernet

I was wondering what the protocol is for Ethernet to reestablish interrupted communication and how long this takes. Maybe this info depends on the devices connected by Ethernet?

Answer (score 0):

Ethernet is a physical layer and data link layer protocol family. On the data link layer, there is no concept for a connection, so there is no way to reestablish anything that might or might not have been there before.

On the physical layer, a link is either up and transmitting, or it's down and not transmitting. Establishing a link from *disconnected* over *connect but not up yet* to *up* takes both sides to detect the other side's carrier.

With fiber links, there is just the carrier. Carrier detection takes a few hundred bit times.

With twisted-pair links, there is (optional) Auto MDI-X detection first, taking a multiple of 62 ms until a working match is found. Then there is autonegotiation (speed, duplex mode, master/slave for 1000BASE-T onwards) using *fast link pulses* (FLP). An FLP burst takes 8-24 ms. 1000BASE-T and faster links also need to match the four lanes/pairs (in PCS), but (as far as I can find) this can be neglected. All in all, a twisted-pair link should come up within 20-250 ms.